# how to define Unable to Replicate App Review Crash?

Tags: ios, app-store, review

We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue. But works well in Simulator and real device.

Review device details:

- Device type: iPad
- OS version: iOS 17.2

```
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":6,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Abort trap: 6","byProc":"eczane","byPid":8878},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":968348,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":179328,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1512244,"symbol":"-[NSException init]","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":1095164,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1095536,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":9896,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":17152,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":29772,"symbol":"_dispatch_queue_override_invoke","symbolLocation":928,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":89060,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain","symbolLocation":392,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":91116,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread2","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":6440,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":6660,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}],
  "faultingThread" : 2,
  "threads" : [{"id":2177213,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":7260910325,"symbolLocation":45,"symbol":"_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_UIView(NUIContainerView|_NUISizeCache|NUISubclassHelpers|NUIPrivate|NUIClassCheck|_NUIGridArrangement|NUIContainerViewHack|NUITestExtras)"},{"value":6513313714,"objc-selector":"focusItemsInRect:"},{"value":12},{"value":6474252288},{"value":9976823808},{"value":12},{"value":0},{"value":11404759},{"value":17},{"value":10799237240},{"value":5},{"value":6504428466,"objc-selector":""},{"value":8885248},{"value":3},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":24},{"value":7260910325,"symbolLocation":45,"symbol":"_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_UIView(NUIContainerView|_NUISizeCache|NUISubclassHelpers|NUIPrivate|NUIClassCheck|_NUIGridArrangement|NUIContainerViewHack|NUITestExtras)"},{"value":12},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6513313714,"objc-selector":"focusItemsInRect:"},{"value":7966717288,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDimmingView"},{"value":0},{"value":7966722208,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView"},{"value":7},{"value":7966173476,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"runtimeLock"},{"value":7966194144,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":4292110977},{"value":6509756416,"objc-selector":"eIsOn"}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":3185170842932992540},"cpsr":{"value":1073745920},"fp":{"value":6128065600},"sp":{"value":6128065536},"esr":{"value":2449473543,"description":"(Data Abort) byte read Translation fault"},"pc":{"value":6475212608},"far":{"value":0}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":42816,"symbol":"getMethodNoSuper_nolock(objc_class*, objc_selector*)","symbolLocation":1552,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":39452,"symbol":"lookUpImpOrForward","symbolLocation":448,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":37296,"symbol":"object_getMethodImplementation","symbolLocation":448,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":93944,"symbol":"UIViewCommonInitWithFrame","symbolLocation":800,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":93064,"symbol":"-[UIView initWithFrame:]","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1323884,"symbol":"-[UIDimmingView initWithFrame:]","symbolLocation":48,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1323640,"symbol":"-[UISheetPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:]","symbolLocation":272,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1323312,"symbol":"-[_UIRootPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingWindow:]","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1639388,"symbol":"-[UIWindow setRootViewController:]","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3237476,"symbol":"-[UIWindowScene _loadWindowWithStoryboardIfNeeded:]","symbolLocation":564,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3236880,"symbol":"-[UIWindowScene _readySceneForConnection]","symbolLocation":108,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1649892,"symbol":"+[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:]","symbolLocation":928,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":2424460,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:]","symbolLocation":808,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":2423220,"symbol":"-[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]","symbolLocation":360,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":2422752,"symbol":"-[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:]","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":63188,"symbol":"-[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:]","symbolLocation":324,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":62832,"symbol":"__92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.108","symbolLocation":280,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":57756,"symbol":"-[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:]","symbolLocation":168,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":106380,"symbol":"__92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":352,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":17152,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":32072,"symbol":"_dispatch_block_invoke_direct","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":42272,"symbol":"__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__","symbolLocation":52,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":42144,"symbol":"-[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible]","symbolLocation":240,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":41848,"symbol":"-[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":225580,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":222120,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSource0","symbolLocation":176,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":215900,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSources0","symbolLocation":244,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":211096,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":828,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":210040,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":13560,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2278956,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":888,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":2276456,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":340,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4547536,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":43880,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":24012,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2240,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":2177214,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6128627712},{"value":3591},{"value":6128091136},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6128627712},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8382724604},"far":{"value":0}}},{"triggered":true,"id":2177215,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":10000000},{"value":110},{"value":0},{"value":90302054965124602},{"value":90302052369640954},{"value":1000},{"value":6129199376},{"value":0},{"value":4294967195},{"value":16},{"value":0},{"value":328},{"value":6129201152},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":5891},{"value":6129201376},{"value":276},{"value":0},{"value":6129201376},{"value":7966188608,"symbolLocation":1536,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queues"},{"value":1535},{"value":7981210948,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_dispatch_continuation_cache_limit"},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8382740096},"cpsr":{"value":1073745920},"fp":{"value":6129200400},"sp":{"value":6129200368},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7803772860,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":0}},"queue":"com.apple.root.default-qos","frames":[{"imageOffset":40892,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":22144,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":482340,"symbol":"__abort","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":482204,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":192,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":86008,"symbol":"abort_message","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":20368,"symbol":"demangling_terminate_handler()","symbolLocation":348,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":191908,"symbol":"_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":144,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":82876,"symbol":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":82784,"symbol":"std::terminate()","symbolLocation":108,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":17172,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":29772,"symbol":"_dispatch_queue_override_invoke","symbolLocation":928,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":89060,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain","symbolLocation":392,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":91116,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread2","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":6440,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":6660,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}]},{"id":2177216,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6129774592},{"value":4867},{"value":6129238016},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6129774592},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8382724604},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2177217,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6130348032},{"value":10499},{"value":6129811456},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6130348032},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8382724604},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2177218,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","threadState":{"x":[{"value":268451845},{"value":21592279046},{"value":8589934592},{"value":49490908151808},{"value":50332160},{"value":49490908151808},{"value":2},{"value":4294967295},{"value":18446744073709550527},{"value":11523},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":11523},{"value":2095104},{"value":2043},{"value":2449610812},{"value":18446744073709551569},{"value":2451707899},{"value":0},{"value":4294967295},{"value":2},{"value":49490908151808},{"value":50332160},{"value":49490908151808},{"value":6130916728},{"value":8589934592},{"value":21592279046},{"value":21592279046},{"value":4412409862}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":7803735824},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":6130916576},"sp":{"value":6130916496},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7803736440},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":4472,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":3856,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":3624,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":3176,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":219932,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":211476,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":210040,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":181388,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":366412,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":1631400,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":420,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":720352,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":732,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":9428,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":6672,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":11}]},{"id":2177219,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6131494912},{"value":17411},{"value":6130958336},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6131494912},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8382724604},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2177220,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6132068352},{"value":21251},{"value":6131531776},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6132068352},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8382724604},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":2177221,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6652,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":11}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6132641792},{"value":18947},{"value":6132105216},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6132641792},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8382724604},"far":{"value":0}}}],
```

I want to resolve that crash, but I can't define bug.

Comment: Please do not post a link to the crash log. Instead, copy and paste, as text, the relevant portion of a symbolicated crash log directly into your question.

Comment: That's not a symbolicated crash log. You need to open the crash log in Xcode and it will prompt you to select the associated project. Then it will show you where in your code the crash happened.

Comment: How to open crash log with Xcode ?

Comment: Xcode -> File -> Open... Make sure your crash log has an ips file extension.

Answer (score 0):

test it on Real iPad with iOS 17.2 and you will find the problem.

iOS 17.2 have a significant differences than 17 or 16. make sure to update your iPad

Comment: Thanks for answer. I fixed app and release App Store.